# Excel Ceiling function equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql

Do we have excel like ceiling function in SQL? I need below in SQL.

1.1 -------  1.5
1.2 -------  1.5
1.3 -------  1.5
1.4 -------  1.5
1.5 -------  1.5
1.6 -------  2.0

Comment: Shockingly, it is called `ceiling()`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818(v=sql.110).aspx.

Comment: Step 1: https://www.google.com/search?q=ceiling+in+sql+server

Answer (score 10):

It can be achieved with:

```
select 0.5 * ceiling(1.2/0.5)  -- result -> 1.5
select 0.5 * ceiling(1.5/0.5)  -- result -> 1.5
select 0.5 * ceiling(1.6/0.5)  -- result -> 2
```